# How to do IPC using Unix Domain Socket in D?

Tags: d, unix-socket

Here I have a program that wants to

1. detect whether if it's the only instance

   1.1. it does that by trying to create a Unix Domain Socket
   and trying to binding it to a specific address.
2. if a duplicate program is not running, establish an UDS
   and then listen to the socket.

   2.1. if any message comes through that socket, the program will log the incoming message

   2.2. otherwise it should keep listening to the socket forever
3. if there's a duplicate program it should send a message and then exit.

Here's what I have:

```d
import std.socket, std.experimental.logger;

immutable string socketAddress = "\0/tmp/com.localserver.myapp";

void main()
{
    auto socket = new std.socket.Socket(std.socket.AddressFamily.UNIX,
            std.socket.SocketType.STREAM);
    auto addr = new std.socket.UnixAddress(socketAddress);

    auto isUnique = () {
        bool result;

        scope (success)
            log("returns: ", result);

        try
        {
            socket.bind(addr);
            result = true;
        }
        catch (std.socket.SocketOSException e)
            result = false;

        // else throw error
        return result;
    }();

    if (isUnique)
    {
        log("Unique instance detected. Listening...");
        // works upto now
        char[] buffer = [];
        while (1)
        {
            socket.listen(0);
            socket.receive(buffer);
            if (buffer != []) {
                log("Received message: ", buffer);
            }
            buffer = [];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log("Duplicate instance detected.");
        socket.connect(addr);
        import std.stdio;
        stdout.write("Enter your message:\t");
        socket.send(readln());
        log("Message has been sent. Exiting.");
    }
}
```

The documentation does not seem very friendly to those who does not have any experience in socket programming. How can I send and receive message with std.socket.Socket?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in your code but I have written recently an example you might find useful [Protocol Buffers and BSD Sockets](https://bitbucket.org/janihur/d-ex/src/master/protocol-buffers-hello-2/). The socket part is based on Adam D. Ruppe's book ;) Hope it helps !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After binding, you actually need to `accept`. It will return a new Socket instance which you can actually `receive` from. Your client side branch looks ok. I think that is your key mistake here.

I also have a code sample in my book that shows basic functionality of std.socket which can help as an example:
http://arsdnet.net/dcode/book/chapter_02/03/

it is tcp, but making it unix just means changing the family, like you already did in your code.

You can also look up socket tutorials for C and so on, the D socket is just a thin wrapper around those same BSD style socket functions.

Comment: Applying the accept() method and using the returned socket results into `SocketAcceptException` due to  `Unable to accept socket connection: Invalid argument`.  Source: https://run.dlang.io/is/2vXzIf

Comment: you gave it an empty buffer. try `char[1024] buffer; receive(buffer[])` instead. note receive returns how much of the buffer was actually used.

Comment: Issue still persists "Unable to accept socket connection: Invalid argument" https://run.dlang.io/is/jcUvU4

Comment: ah another look reveals more i missed: you need to `listen` before oyu can accept. Listening is done by the first socket, not the receiver socket. After it is listening (btw use a non-zero arg to listen), THEN you can accept. The order of these things matters, see my example code to see a working example

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However why is not 0 desirable for `listen(int backlog)`'s argument? the documentation says that `backlog` is a request of how many pending incoming connections are queued until accepted. Does it mean that the message will be listened in every two incoming messages?

Comment: it just means if you are busy managing one connection it will refuse the next one and that might lead to a mistaken case on single instance checking - the client gets rejected, assumes it is the only copy and then spawns another one. though come to think of it the bind should still throw there so probably ok here

Answer (score 0):

As Adam pointed out I had use `listen()` method first and then apply the `accept()` method which returns a socket that can receive message. Then the receiver socket takes a `char[N]` buffer.

```d
import std.socket, std.experimental.logger;

class UDSIPC
{
private:
    static immutable string socketAddress = "\0/tmp/com.localserver.myapp";
    static immutable size_t messageBufferSize = 64;
    static immutable string socketAddressName = "\0/tmp/com.localserver.myapp";
    Socket socket;
    UnixAddress uaddr;

public:
    this(in string socketAddressName = socketAddressName)
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.UNIX, SocketType.STREAM);
        uaddr = new UnixAddress(socketAddress);
    }

    bool getUniqueness()
    {
        bool result;

        scope (success)
            log("returns: ", result);

        try
        {
            socket.bind(uaddr);
            result = true;
        }
        catch (SocketOSException e)
            result = false;

        // else throw error
        return result;
    }

    string getMessage()
    {
        socket.listen(0);
        auto receiverSocket = socket.accept();
        char[messageBufferSize] buffer;
        auto amount = receiverSocket.receive(buffer);
        import std.string;
        return format!"%s"(buffer[0 .. amount]);
    }

    void sendMessage(in string message)
    {
        socket.connect(uaddr);
        socket.send(message);
    }

}

void main()
{
    auto ipc = new UDSIPC();

    if (ipc.getUniqueness())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            log(ipc.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        import std.stdio, std.string;
        ipc.sendMessage(readln().chomp());
    }
}
```